# Automatically refresh SQL Server backend with daily updated Access table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, odbc, dsn

**Summary:** I have a local Access database which contains orders and is updated daily in the morning by an automatic VBA routine, started by a Windows task. In detail, every day new orders will be added and existing orders will be updated with new information using a local `.csv` file which is dropped in a shared folder environment on 5:30am in the morning.

Now, I have a SQL Server which needs to be up to date and an exact replica of the local table, in the best case right after the local update has been made. This is necessary because I use the SQL Server as a backend for an automatic order distribution tool which will be used by about 50 employees in the future.

**What I have tried:** I'm running the local update routine entirely on a local table which is and will always be a local one to ensure a smooth update process. In order to update the SQL table I tried to realize it by creating a linked table, however, the datasets are not transferred over to SQL Server. This is weird, because when I change single fields manually in the linked table, the changes are reflected immediately in the SQL Server table. It's only the VBA-based processes which are not updated in the SQL Server.

**Code:**

```
Sub Sync_SQL()

Dim myDB As DAO.Database
Set myDB = CurrentDb

Dim strSQL As String

Dim qdf As QueryDef

' Erstellt einen temporären Query mit einem ODBC-Connection String zur Verbindung mit dem SQL Server
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("SyncDB")
qdf.Connect = "ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};server=XX.X.XXX.XX;database=OPM;uid=USID;pwd=PWD;"

' Löscht alle noch offenen Aufträge aus dem SQL-Server
qdf.SQL = "DELETE FROM [OPM].[dbo].[ReiseMaster] WHERE NOT [Name of Employee] = '---------';"
qdf.ReturnsRecords = False

' Führt den Query aus und misachtet dabei jegliche Dialogfelder
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "SyncDB"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

' Fügt aktuell offene Aufträge in den SQL-Server ein
myDB.Execute "INSERT INTO [dbo_ReiseMaster] SELECT * FROM [ReiseMaster] WHERE NOT [Name of Employee] = '---------';"

' Leert den Statistik-Table (sollte in Zukunft anders funktionieren)
qdf.SQL = "DELETE FROM [OPM].[dbo].[Statistics];"
qdf.ReturnsRecords = False

' Führt den Query aus und misachtet dabei jegliche Dialogfelder
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "SyncDB"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

' Lädt den Statistik-Table mit den neuen Werten hoch (sollte in Zukunft nur noch für neue Aufträge erfolgen, um Performance auch nach längerer Laufzeit der Datenbank gering zu halten)
myDB.Execute "INSERT INTO [dbo_Statistics] SELECT * FROM [Statistics];"

' Setzt die aktive Verbindung zurück und löscht den temporären Query
Set qdf = Nothing
myDB.QueryDefs.Delete "SyncDB"
myDB.QueryDefs.Refresh

End Sub
```

---

**Result:** In particular, the following changes to the linked table will not be reflected in SQL Server:

```
myDB.Execute "INSERT INTO [dbo_ReiseMaster] SELECT * FROM [ReiseMaster] WHERE NOT [Name of Employee] = '---------';"
```

While the linked table `dbo_ReiseMaster` within the Access file contains the updated values, they are not being uploaded to the SQL Server.

How can I ensure that the local Access table (in what variations I'm manipulating the data whatsoever) will always transfer the changes over to SQL Server?

Comment: Have you checked in an Access query that the SELECT part `SELECT * FROM [ReiseMaster] WHERE NOT [Name of Employee] = '---------';` actually returns records?

Comment: Hi Andre, yes I've checked that. There are basically 10.000 records with an actual employee name and they are returned using that statement. I also just noticed, that there is actually no insertion into the linked table `dbo_ReiseMaster`. For testing I deleted all the records with a name in the linked table and run this statement above. While the SELECT part returns me a record, I can't find this data in the linked table.

Comment: Hm, try `myDB.Execute "INSERT ...", dbFailOnError` to get error info.

Comment: Is dbo_ReiseMaster linked to Access with an ODBC connection? Or are you manually connecting using VBA each time?

Comment: dbo_ReiseMaster is linked via an ODBC connection, so it should be permanently connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a single connection object and then "hope" that access knows what table to use. You executing sql on a single connection object, so the insert and source tables will reside on that one remote connection. You can't do that.

What would happen if the source table existed sql server side?

However, dump all that query connection stuff. Simply link the tables to the server.

You can now write and use standard sql from access, and use both tables as if they were local.

So, you can go:
dim strSQL     as string

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [ReiseMasterLinked] " & _
        "SELECT * FROM [ReiseMaster] WHERE NOT [Name of Employee] = '---------';"

currentdb.Execute strSQL
```

So, you can use sql against two tables, even if one is linked to sql server, but you have to use linked tables. You don't deal with, or see or use the connection object, as that is always going to apply to one connection object. However, Access is VERY special in that you can write sql that includes linked tables and local tables - and it will resolve the connection that the two tables are based on (or in fact that one table is not linked is local and the  other is a linked table.

## Edit

Here is another example. But NOTE how I commented out the .Execute command, and replaced it with a docmd.RunSQL.

```
Sub AppendTest()

  Dim strSQL     As String
  
  strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblHotelsSQL " & _
           "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsLOCAL WHERE NOT tblHotelsLOCAL.HotelName = '-----'"

  'CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
  DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
  
End Sub
```

This runs slower, and wraps the command in a transaction - so you can answer yes, or no to the prompt, but it gives a MUCH more detailed error message as to why the query could not, or did not run. And again, note how no connection strings are required. For above to work, one could do a quick double click on the linked table to SQL server to ensure that the linked table is all working fine (and if it shows data - perhaps try editing one row - move off and this will ensure that the linked table is read/write.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you are pointing at. Given that explanation, my expected outcome was not really a defined one. However, I'm not sure what you mean with "Simply link the tables to the server.", because I actually use a link (Import >> Link). `dbo_ReiseMaster` is a linked table and this is why I tried to execute on this table as it is a normal Access table as seen in my code above.

Comment: Ah, ok, then you can 100% dispense with any "connection" stuff in your code. You can use in-line sql, or modify a existing query, but that query will be a standard query - no need to use/mess with connection string in code.

Comment: see my new edit + suggestion in my post - it gives you some things to test/try. Once you get the docmd.runSQL working fine, then change the code over to the CurrentDB.Execute - that gets rid of the transaction and the yes/no prompt to actually do the update.